# SAP B1 Studio for Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

I would like to know how and where to download the SAP B1 Studio extension to Visual Studio. I found some topics in stackoverflow and the SAP community, but none of the topics are explained where I can get this extension.

[enter image description here][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/F1AaL.png

Comment: The setup files to install SAP B1 should have the .exe to install the SAP B1 Studio extension to Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

You have to install the SAP B1 SDK,

The SDK is included with any Business One patch or installer, in a subfolder called "Packages\SAP Business One SDK".

https://andresnaranjo.files.wordpress.com/2010/09/tb1300_en_col92.pdf

[image]

Comment: In my version of the SAP B1 SDK there is no such folder.

Comment: The SDK is included with any Business One patch or installer, in a subfolder called "Packages\SAP Business One SDK".
If you do not have a patch or installer, you will need to contact your SAP partner to obtain it.